# author name formatting in plainnat

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I typed in the preamble

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
\newcommand{\bibfont}{times}
```

Then at the end

```
\bibliography{mybibfile}{}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\nocite{*}
```

In bib file I wrote e.g.

```
@article{colizza08,
title = "Epidemic modeling in metapopulation systems with heterogeneous coupling pattern:       Theory and simulations",
journal = "Journal of Theoretical Biology",
volume = "251",
number = "",
pages = "450-467",
year = "2008",
url = "",
author = "Vittoria Colizza and Alessandro Vespignani",
}
```

In tex file I cite as `\citep{colizza08}`

I want to appear in paper as:

> Colizza, V., Vespignani, A., 2008. Epidemic modeling in metapopulation
>   systems with heterogeneous coupling pattern: theory and
>   simulations. J.Theor.Biol. 251, 450–467.

while I get:

> Vittoria Colizza and Alessandro Vespignani. Epidemic modeling in metapopulation systems
>   with heterogeneous coupling pattern: Theory and simulations. Journal of
>   Theoretical Biology, 251:450–467, 2008.

Even if I write
  `author = "Colizza,V. and Vespignani,A.",`

I still get:

> V. Colizza and A. Vespignani. Epidemic modeling in metapopulation systems

So how do I mak the author name appears in order: surname, first letter of 1st name, with the same output I want?

Comment: I recommend to switch to biblatex.

Comment: @ Marco Daniel thank you. but this sort names alphabetically according to the first name, and not the last name! and consequently cite as (first name et. al. 2008)

Comment: But you can easily change it by `DeclareNameFormat`

Comment: I did not know about this, I will try. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to achieve the desired author name format using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). (The `authoryear-comp` style is a rough equivalent of `natbib` with author-year format plus `cite`.) For general information about customizing the bibliography format, see [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{colizza08,
title = "Epidemic modeling in metapopulation systems with heterogeneous coupling pattern:       Theory and simulations",
journal = "Journal of Theoretical Biology",
volume = "251",
number = "",
pages = "450-467",
year = "2008",
url = "",
author = "Vittoria Colizza and Alessandro Vespignani",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]