# author year style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I have asked about a specific referencing style and was recommended to use biblatex.
I was given a nice answer
[author name formatting in plainnat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56723/author-order-in-plainnat)

but then I would like to make minor changes:

1. The "et al." just in citing, but in references I want full author list for a paper
2. bold volume number
3. delete the "In:" preceding the journal name

I would like to know if I can add simple things to the code of the answer :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For (1) use the package options `maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=99`. See also my updated answer to [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography).

For (2) add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

For (3) see [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex).